# Создание ключа в Firebird

Tags: firebird, sql

Как указать ключ в таблице базы данных Firebird?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add constraint PK_TABLE_NAME_1
    primary key (RRR)
```

Где **RRR** это имя поля

Answer (score 1):

Ответ на [CONSTRAINT](http://firebirdsql.su/doku.php?id=constraint):

> Зарезервированное слово CONSTRAINT языка SQL сервера Firebird служит для работы с ограничениями ссылочной целостности создаваемых в базе данных таблиц.